# How to get block layout programmatically?

Tags: theming, 8, blocks, navigation

Sorry there won't much details but the title is self explanatory.

I need to fetch the block layout of the front page and build a menu from it.

So the question is: How can I get that list programmatically?

Comment: Menus are contained within blocks, blocks are placed in a region to output the menu. Why not just create a menu and output the block?

Comment: @Kevin what I need to do is creating a dynamic menu with links to latest nodes of a specific content types/views or remove them from the menu completely if there is no content for that type/view/block. Can I achieve this with Drupal's menu system?

Comment: @Tim, see the code example for the question about the block layout in my answer. Your comment seems to be more about the content of blocks, not if and where they are placed in the block layout. Don't see how this is connected.

Comment: @4k4 Yes. I was thinking that I can achieve my goal if I can get the list of blocks but now I realise that is not possible since not all the blocks will go into the menu and it's not feasible to distinguish them by their names. Yet, yours is the right answer to what I asked, so I'll accept that. Feel free to comment on the dynamic menu issue. :)

Comment: Your menu is the same like a view, which tries to pull information to use them in a contextual filter. Most times you get them from the request/route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the block layout programmatically from the configured blocks by going through each region defined in the current theme:

```
  $block_layout = [];
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme();
  $regions = $theme->getRegions();
  foreach ($regions as $region) {  
    $blocks = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('block')
      ->loadByProperties(['theme' => $theme->getname(), 'region' => $region]);
    uasort($blocks, 'Drupal\block\Entity\Block::sort');
    $block_layout[$region] = array_keys($blocks);
  }
```

This is without checking if the blocks are visible on the front page. That would be difficult, because the visibility condition plugins are context aware and only provide a correct result when they are called in a real front page context.